# Which gems are most valuable?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I've got a lot of shards filling my inventory, and despite the fact that they're weightless, I'd like to get rid of them... in the most profitable way possible, of course.

Turning them into gems seems the easy way out, but some gems are more valuable than others -- so which are they?

What's the best way to make money off of my sagecrafting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what i noticed the most profitable gems so far are this ones:

- Gem of Devouring (weapon gem,psyhical+magical lambent) = 5,9k w/o points in mercentile.
- Gem of Ferocity  (weapon gem,magic+magic lambent)      = 5,9k w/o points in mercentile.

Gems made from pristine shards will give you even more money,and i believe the same combinations i mentioned above will be most profitable for pristine gems as well.

If you want to know the pricing of other gems you can check [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Arro4SyEbmqudGJ1bm41SDVQbnNlVnE3NEhmSjhZeFE#gid=0) sheet.

That sheet was made by Teleri from official *Amalur* forum,and the source thread is [here](http://forums.reckoning.amalur.com/showthread.php?4536-guide-for-gem-stones).

(Do note that Teleri had 1-2 points in mercantile when making the pricing sheet)